# How to run patching program as sudo with Wine?

Tags: 14.04, permissions, wine, games

I've recently installed Wine on my Ubuntu 14.04. When I'm trying to patch a game I get the following error:

`Please run the patching program again with full administrative rights!`

So I tried to run it this way:

`sudo wine Patch.exe`

But I get an error:

`wine: /home/myusername/.wine is not owned by you`

I tried `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/myusername/.wine` but the error still appears.

Please do not tell me that I should not run Wine programs as sudo!

Can someone help me with a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Can you find out who it is owned by? `ls -al /home/myusername/.wine`

Comment: @levlaz Every file/directory is owned by "myusername".

Comment: I tell you not to use wine with sudo! When you run wine with sudo, you run wine as user root. Means the folder has to be owned by root and not by you. Besides: Security issue! You know how much Windows malware exists - especially in non-official/illegal patches, cheat- or crack-progs. I guess you need Windows-admin rights here, not Ubuntu root privileges. Better find a way to run a program in wine with win-admin rights than to run wine with root rights!

Comment: @ByteCommander No worries. This is legal/official patch for the game... but thanks.

Comment: Don't run it with `sudo`. That is almost certainly why you're getting the error. There's no reason to and you're running as `root` who doesn't own `/home/myusername/.wine`. Just don't use `sudo`!

Comment: There is NO REASON to run anything in wine as ROOT. http://wiki.winehq.org/SecuringWine "Unless you run Wine as root, for instance, it's hard for malicious software in Wine to modify files belonging to other users. But Wine doesn't protect you against malware you run yourself."

Comment: There can absolutely be good reasons to run things in wine as root. Obviously caution is in order, but that doesn't mean there aren't things you want to do which require root privileges. For example, trying to create a USB boot disk from an official BIOS update package.

Answer (score 0):

Never ever run wine with sudo ! This will give windows viruses the power to change all your system, because you give them super-user permissions.

Comment: How does this answer the question?